# Fixing potentiometer tracks on a ribbon

Tags: potentiometer

Out of curiosity if it's anyhow possible, cost is not the primary focus here.

Are there any special methods of creating carbon tracks on a ribbon?

Example ribbon with carbon track:
[image: https://modulemaster.com/rebuilds/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/SAM_3111-copy.jpg]

Beside moving the head to a bit different position to use the not broken part of the carbon track can one fix somehting like this in home or using some thirdparty solutions?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken that looks like the feedback sensor of a throttle valve. I recall hearing about non-contact pots using a magnetic encoding. Those are not susceptible to wear like that.

Comment: You can buy conductive carbon paint on the intertubes.

Comment: Can you add something that will be conductive? probably. Can you add it in a way that it will have the same properties as the stock part? very unlikely.

Comment: yes there is a counter part without the ribbon.

Well a humand made this track so I though it's possible to do it again, maybe "overwriting" the old one even, I just dont know the process of making it.

Comment: A human designed the machine that made the potentiometer.  Potentiometers aren't made by hand.

Answer (score 1):

The part that's worn - **may** just be a 'jumper' -- the resistance may not matter as the slider shorts across.

But I think displacing the element sideways is probably your best bet.

The polyimide film is screen printed with a specific type of resistive ink, which is then cured in an oven. Not rocket science but not very practical for one piece unless you're in the business.